# Docker image env variables overwritten by local machine

Tags: bash, docker

Why is it that when checking the `env` for an image I create, I get the image environment variables listed as expected, but when I try to access one of those env variables (i.e. $PATH), I'm getting my local machines environment variable output instead?

I believe I misunderstand how docker environment variables work. I'm attempting to run some commands against a docker container and am seeing what I consider unexpected behavior. I have created a simple example to try to demonstrate.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:12.13.0 

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/custom-path/goes-here"
```

**Commands:**

1. `docker build . -tag env-test`
2. `docker run env-test /bin/bash -c "env"`
3. `docker run env-test /bin/bash -c "$PATH"`

**Expected Output from final two commands.**

2. `docker run env-test /bin/bash -c "env".`

```
...
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/custom-path/goes-here
...
```

3. `docker run evn-test /bin/bash -c "echo $PATH"`

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/custom-path/goes-here
```

**Actual Output from final two commands**

2. `docker run env-test /bin/bash -c "env".`

```
...
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/custom-path/goes-here
...
```

3. `docker run evn-test /bin/bash -c "echo $PATH"`

```
/Users/local-machine-user/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/local-machine-user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/local-machine-user/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
```

The output of running `echo $PATH` against the created image is returning my local machines $PATH variable. What?

The primary thing I'm trying to do is execute a script against the docker image that requires those environment variables I set in the image, but the script fails because the environment variables the script uses end up being for my local machine and not the ones specified in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you're trying to run your third example

```sh
docker run env-test /bin/bash -c "echo $PATH"
```

The first thing that happens here is that your local shell processes this command and does its usual set of expansions.  Environment variable references in double quotes are expanded, for example.  Once it's built the final command line, then the shell executes it.

A generally useful trick is to just put `echo` at the front of the command

```sh
echo docker run env-test /bin/bash -c "echo $PATH"
```

This will show you the command that would have been run, but not actually run it.

To make this work you need to cause your local shell to not expand environment variables, so that the shell you're launching in the container can do it.  Either single quotes or backslash escaping will work for this

```sh
docker run env-test /bin/sh -c 'echo $PATH'
docker run env-test /bin/sh -c "echo \$PATH"
```

> The primary thing I'm trying to do is execute a script against the docker image that requires those environment variables I set in the image

The best way to approach this is probably to write a normal shell script and `COPY` it into your image.  This saves both layers of quoting and confusion around which shell is processing things like variables.  If you can't modify the image, an alternative is to bind-mount a script from the host.

```sh
# If the script is in the image
docker run --rm env-test path-echoer.sh

# If not
docker run --rm -v $PWD:/scripts env-test /scripts/path-echoer.sh
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, that makes complete sense that it's being evaluated first. So, the trouble is, the script is actually already inside the image and having this issue. This is a bit of red herring perhaps. I'm going to do a bit of digging to make sure I'm not doing something else like what you're describing

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the dollar sign when using `$PATH` in a string - `"echo \$PATH"`

What happens is that when running this line:

```
docker run evn-test /bin/bash -c "echo $PATH"
```

Bash first translate `$PATH`, then passes that string into the docker container. So the command that is ran inside the container is:

```
docker run evn-test /bin/bash -c "echo /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```